# Open URLs in a hidden mode without redirection

Tags: php

Page 1:

```
<form method="GET">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Start">
</form>
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
fopen('http://localhost/sn/test2.php?name=ttest11&post=hi1&submit=Start
','r');

fopen('http://localhost/sn/test3.php?name=ttest22&post=hi2&submit=Start
','r');


fopen('http://localhost/sn/test4.php?name=ttest33&post=hi3&submit=Start
','r');
}
?>
```

Page test2, test3, test3...:

```
<form method="get">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="14" maxlength="20">
<input type="text" name="post" id="post" size="5" maxlength="5" >
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Start">
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
// ..... hidden code, to sent messages...... 
}

?>
```

Pages test2, test3, test4 are programmed to send emails when I click on the button start below, or if I start directly the link.

```
http://localhost/sn/test2.php?name=ttest11&post=hi1&submit=Start
```

A message will be sent automatically.

My problem is: I want when I click on the start button on the first page, the other pages' (test2, test3, test4) links start in a hidden mode (to send emails be link), and without redirection or anything, just (on click) all the links will be started. Then automatically the emails will be sent

I really need help, please.

Comment: Usually that is done on server side, so you transfer one form and then on the server side a controller decides what actions to fire. That might well be several action, up to using a job queue where you can put jobs into that will be processed in an asynchronous mode. An alternative would be to call the different "pages" via ajax in background from the client side. Works, but the first variant is probably the better approach in general.

Answer (score 1):

You should try ajax functionality. Ajax and call any page asynchronously and perform php task. 
 i.e.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
```